# Getting the latest file name etc using glob.glob & max (os.path.getctime)

Tags: python, list, time, max, glob

I am trying to get the file name of the latest file on a directory which has couple hundred files on a network drive.

Basically the idea is to snip the file name (its the date/time the file was downloaded, eg `xyz201912191455.csv`) and paste it on a `config file` every time the script is run.

Now the `list_of_files` usually run in about a second but `latest_file` takes about 100 seconds which is extremely slow.

Is there a faster way to extract the information about the latest file?

The code sample as below:

```
import os
import glob
import time
from configparser import ConfigParser
import configparser
list_of_files = glob.glob('filepath\*', recursive=True)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

list_of_files2 = glob.glob('filepath\*', recursive=True)
latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: Probably not using python functions. Have you considered using OS functionality, e.g., a bash command `ls -t filepath/* | head -1` in linux?

Comment: If you are not using `**` within your search pattern, you can turn `recursive=False`, but I'm not sure if this will save a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I initially was searching for only csv files but found that redundant, and tested recursive=False as well but it did not increase the speed that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filenames already include the datetime, why bother getting their stat information? And if the names are like `xyz201912191455.csv`, one could use `[-16:-4]` to extract `201912191455` and as these are zero padded they will sort lexicographically in numerical order. Also `recursive=True` is not needed here as the pattern does not have a `**` in it.

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('filepath\*')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=lambda n: n[-16:-4])
```

Comment: This is a good point! I usually run these on folders with combined dates but actually the current one does not have any so I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Cheers this actually reduced the time to 1.71 seconds! Perfect solution to the problem!